# How to Style H1 Tag with Javascript in Squarespace Template

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

Our Squarespace site has a catalogue containing products from multiple brands. I'm trying to ensure the brand name stands out by making it bold but given the way Squarespace works, I need to add Javascript into the page to manipulate the html.

Using Chrome Dev tools on the product titles, I can see the html class is called '.ProductList h1.ProductList-title'.

I've tried implementing the below, but haven't had much luck so far - am I even on the right track?

```
function changeBrandName() 
{
  var prodList = document.getElementsByClassName(".ProductList h1.ProductList-title");
  for (i = 0, len = prodList.length; i < len; i++) 
  {
    prodList[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
}

window.onload = changeBrandName();
```

Squarespace class structure:

```
<section class="ProductList-overlay">
          <div class="ProductList-meta">
            <h1 class="ProductList-title">Vifa - Pebble Grey Oslo Loudspeaker</h1><style></style>                                                 
            <div class="product-price">
<span class="sqs-money-native">0.00</span>
</div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

(this is one of the pages we're displaying products https://www.manilva.co/catalogue-electronics/).

Comment: your code is trying to modify the name of each item offered - yet your question is saying you want to modify the "brand" - is this Manilva, at the top left? that is an image.... you cannot bold an image thru CSS unless you provide a new image with bolded text.

Comment: You need not write the css selectors inside getElementsByClassName function instead write only the name of class try this inside your console tab of chrome Dev tools 

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("ProductList-title"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

when using getElementsByClassName, you do not need to pass in CSS selectors, like you have done. You just need to pass in the actual name of the classes. Or, use the querySelectorAll with the parameters you had originally. querySelector, as daksh mentioned, will only return the first element that matches

```
function changeBrandName()
{
  var prodList = document.querySelectorAll(".ProductList h1.ProductList-title"); //returns static NodeList of all elements in DOM that match the provided classes
  for (i = 0; i < prodList.length; i++) 
  {
    prodList[i].style.color = 'red';
    prodList[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold'; //W is capital
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for coming back to me - I'm a little new to HTML. I've added the squarespace class structure to the original post, as you can see it's a embedded within the other classes, which one should I be referencing here?

Comment: .ProductList is your entire div - changing the style.color or style.fontWeight of this doesn't directly change anything on your website since you have more specific CSS that overrides this.

h1.ProductList-title is the text of each item, such as "Addon White T3 Speaker"

Comment: Vifa - Pebble Grey Oslo Loudspeaker, and other text like it, will be selected with `h1.ProductList-title`

Comment: That makes sense and I've updated it to specify the h1.ProductList-title exactly, I'm now not seeing errors though the style isn't being applied, so I can only assume there's something overriding it somewhere?

Comment: place code in between your  `script` tags at the bottom of your index.html, on line 1188. this ensures that it has the last say as to what happens on the page. you have plenty more javascript happening after line 100, where your code is currently. the browser renders your index.html from top to bottom as it builds the DOM, and runs javascript as it sees it when reading from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated that you must use Javascript. However, Squarespace supports custom CSS (currently under *Design > Custom CSS* while editing your site). Having read through the question, I see no details that preclude the use of CSS (though perhaps such details were simply left out).

If using CSS is an option, inserting the following via [Custom CSS](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) is all that is needed:

```
.ProductList h1.ProductList-title {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If for some reason you want to target only a specific collection, you can add further specificity to the selector via the collection ID, used as the `id` attribute on the `body` element:

```
#collection-5c1cf955898583ce09da99a0 .ProductList h1.ProductList-title {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you choose to go the CSS route, be sure you evaluate and remove any previous code you've added related to this particular need.

Comment: Hi Brandon! Thanks for responding. The reason I want to go down the JavaScript route is I then intend to only bold the first part of the title e.g. the brand name, followed by the product name not in bold.